# Why was Wonder Woman's costume updated but then immediately reverted to the old one?

Tags: dc, comics, behind-the-scenes, costume, wonder-woman

A Wonder Woman costume fan art I [posted in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37857430#37857430) reminded me of an old question I'd asked here: [In what arc or continuity does Wonder Woman's costume have leggings?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/141958/70236)

In *Wonder Woman* #41 (which is under the *New 52* but predates *Rebirth*), Diana is given a new costume by Hephestos:

[image]
 <sub>Click on the image for full resolution</sub>

Yet in the following arc she goes back to her old costume:

[image]

I've read the adjoining issues, but there wasn't an explanation given in them. This sudden change is also noted in Thaddeus Howze's asnwer to [Are comics shifting away from revealing costumes for women?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/21636/70236)

Since an in-universe reason is likely not available, what was the out-of-universe reason to go back to her old suit? Was it an artistic choice, or something about the reception?

Comment: I have a feeling it was reception. I saw a fair amount of people complaining in forums about the new outfit. Personally, I prefer the classic one, although just adding covered legs wouldn't bother me.

Comment: The first one (WW #41) was drawn in the winter and she was cold so she put pants on.